# How can I efficiently bring branches up to date? (pull with rebase)

Tags: git

Say I have a branch old that is several thousand commits behind.

```
$ git branch -v 
* main [ahead 2] whatever
  old  [ahead 1, behind 3733] something else
```

In order to bring it up to date I have to:

1. `git checkout old`, which brings my working copy several thousand commits behind
2. `git pull -r`, which means

   1. `git fetch`
   2. `git checkout origin/HEAD`, which brings my working directory forward thousands of commits, probably close to where I was to begin with
   3. `git cherry-pick $commit-id`, which reapplies my `something else` commit

Is there a built-in way to optimize this workflow so that I do not have to  go back and forward and check out thousands of file changes only to undo them moments later?

Answer (score 1):

You try something like this:

```
#forcefully replace old branch with the latest origin changes
git branch -f old origin/old
# switch to it
git checkout old
# bring the "something else" commit
git cherry-pick old@{1}
```

However, it is not very nice approach, and only works for single commit.

Not sure why do you want it, is it actually slow to checkout old branches? Usually takes few seconds.

Comment: Yes, it is slow, or I wouldn't have asked this in the first place :) but I can imagine that a rebase on top of the current branch followed by a git branch -f would work